# Optimizing sql query by eliminating of subqueries

Tags: mysql

I'm building a small bidding system and the below query is used to retrieve item information. This includes the title, the owner, bids on the item, who bid and what countries the item can be delivered to.

The query uses subqueries and I would like to increase the speed at which it runs by eliminating those subqueries. How do I get the same result without the subqueries?

Tables used in query:

Items
- contains basic info about an item like title, description, user_id of user who posted the item.

Users
- contains information about users

Bids
- Contains bids. Since an item can have more than one bid, I want the highest bid as well as a few other bids

Countries
- this table contains the countries where the item can be shipped as well as a price for each country

The query:

```
    SELECT t1.id
    ,t1.user_id
    ,t1.item_title
    ,t1.item_number
    ,t1.item_start
    ,t1.item_description
    ,t1.active
    ,t2.first_name
    ,t2.last_name
    ,CAST(t2.fb_id AS CHAR(50)) AS fb_id
    ,t2.user_pic
    ,b.maxbid
    ,b.bids
    ,c.ship_cost
FROM items t1
LEFT JOIN users t2 ON t1.user_id = t2.id
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT item_id
        ,bid
        ,MAX(bid) AS maxbid
        ,COUNT(bid) AS bids
    FROM bids
    GROUP BY item_id
    ) b ON t1.id = b.item_id
JOIN (
    SELECT item_id
        ,ship_cost
    FROM countries_ship
    GROUP BY item_id
    ) c ON t1.id = c.item_id
WHERE t1.active = 1
ORDER BY t1.id DESC LIMIT 12
```

Comment: Your `INNER JOIN` effectively removes effects of preceding `OUTER JOIN`s.  Your last sub-query uses `GROUP BY` without any aggregation.

Comment: perhaps you could add a bit of an explanation of what you're trying to achieve - along with your table schema.  it's not immediately clear what the goal of the query is because the last subquery has an indeterminate result.